# how can I wrap libraries with templated code which requires runtime dispatch and/or inheritence

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, template-meta-programming

*Motivation:* In a suite of software, we make use of multiple unix-philosophied binaries that accomplish various tasks. These binaries will load configuration files of various types (yaml, json, xml, ini) and it's come to the point that we need to wrap these various features up into a tidy wrapper. All of the libraries (simdjson, yamlcpp, rapidxml) come with fairly modern C++ interfaces, but they are all *slightly* different from each other.

For instance, while `yamlcpp` checks the existence of a key simply by casting a node to bool, in `simdjson` you need to get the element and compare its `.error()` value to field not found constant.

All of the above means that subtle bugs are becoming more and more common because of slightly different handling methods, and it is a burden to ask the developer to be weary of each library's idiosyncracy. Also, some libraries load either json or yaml files, and this means that there are two code paths to load the same functional configuration.

Of particular note is that casting is different in each library and the exceptions raised (sometimes none) are not uniform.

(Since this is a one-time startup configuration problem, speed is not a major concern.)

*Solution:* the solution in principle is quite simple. I'd like to create an extremely thin templated wrapper around the libraries.

The problem I'm running into, however, is that the configuration file is fed through at run-time, and so this can't simply be a templated compile-time solution.

*The Question:* having presented the motivation and attempt at solution, here's my problem

Consider the following minimal code:

```
#include <iostream>
class simdjson {};
class YAML {}; // for compilability of example

struct Node
{
   operator int() const { return 123; }
};

template<typename T> struct NodeImpl : public Node
{
   operator int() const;
   /* ... a bunch of common code ... */
};

/* ... tiny bits of specialization ... */
template<> NodeImpl<YAML>::operator int() const {return 42; /* return node.asInt(); */ }
template<> NodeImpl<simdjson>::operator int() const {return 52; /* return node.as<int>(); */}

int main() {
  Node no_worky = NodeImpl<YAML>();
  NodeImpl<YAML> a = NodeImpl<YAML>();
    std::cout << "expect 42, got: " << (int)a  << std::endl
              << "expect 42, got: " << (int)no_worky;
    return 0;
}
```

There are 2 problems:

- the fact that the type of configuration format can be determined at runtime requires this to be something other than a strictly templated solution (hence the inheritence)
- making it inheritence based means that I (think) I have no solution other than virtual pointers and a virtual base Node class. This saddens me that I can't pass around the nodes by value (which I normally would be able to do in a purely templated implementation).

Is there an elegant solution I'm missing here, or is it simply that the runtime constraint means that I am constrained to use virtual base classes.

---

**Edit** after quite a bit of mucking around, I've come to the conclusion that this should be implemented entirely statically, and that the configuration code should be an unspecialized templated call like so:

```
template<typename K> void configure(NodeImpl<K> root)
{
    std::cout << "expect 42, got: " << (int)root  << std::endl;
    /* ... do configuration stuff ... */
}

int main() {

    if( /* file is yaml */ )
        configure(NodeImpl<YAML>());
    else if (/* file is json */)
        configure(NodeImpl<json>());
    return 0;
}
```

At first this felt like code duplication until I realized that one way or another, 2 branches of code will be emitted - whether I hide that behind a virtualization or not.

The above approach is entirely templated, and is entirely more sane.

Comment: `Node` can be your type-erasure type, and it is it which holds the virtual base class.

Comment: Does this/can this solve the by-value nice-to-have?

Comment: Yes, it can. It mostly just wrap a `unique_ptr` and forward to it.